# How to print selected columns from grep using awk

Tags: python, perl, unix, awk, grep

I have the following input,

```
[2014-12-22 10:39:54,668] - 1=1,2=2,3=A,4=1,109=5313F,110=Y,112=20141222-15:40:21.056,150=D,180=C,167=CS
```

The order of fields can be different from line to line.

The goal is to pick up specific fields, such as date, time, 109, 110, 150, 167 to something like

```
2014-12-22,10:39:54,668,109=5313F,110=Y,150=D,167=CS.
```

The difficulty is the field order might be different in different lines, any suggestion on a simple awk script to achieve this or is perl/python better suited?

Comment: If you want to do this in awk, why did you also add the `python` and `perl` tags?

Comment: I'm not fixated on just awk, if python/perl is better suited for this, I'm open to other options.

Comment: what decides the fields?

Comment: Ideally the logic loops through the fields (comma seperated) and test the lhs of = for specific fields, such as 109/110/150/167 and prepend the date & time from the line

Comment: well str.split will do what you want then or re `date,rest = s.split(" - ",1)` will get you started

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may do:

```
awk -F"[][, ]" '{a=$2","$3","$4;for (i=5;i<=NF;i++) if($i~/^1(09|10|50|67)=/) a=a","$i;print a}' file
2014-12-22,10:39:54,668,109=5313F,110=Y,150=D,167=CS
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you have `name=value` pairs in your input, its a good idea to create a name2value array and then use that:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="[][ ,=]"; OFS="," }
{
    for (i=7; i<=NF; i+=2) {
       name2value[$i] = $(i+1)
    }
    print $2, $3, $4, fmt(109), fmt(110), fmt(150), fmt(167)
}
function fmt(name) { return (name "=" name2value[name]) }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
2014-12-22,10:39:54,668,109=5313F,110=Y,150=D,167=CS
```

Answer (score 0):

Awk supports [associative arrays](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html#uh-22). This can help you overcome the field ordering problem as follows:

```
echo "[2014-12-22 10:39:54,668] - 1=1,2=2,3=A,4=1,109=5313F,110=Y,112=20141222-15:40:21.056,150=D,180=C,167=CS" |
  awk -F'[, \\[\\]]' '{ 
    for (i=7; i++ < NF;)
    {
      split($i,parts,"=");
      h[parts[1]]=parts[2]
    }

    printf "%s,%s,%s,109=%s,110=%s,150=%s,167=%s\n ", 
      $2, $3, $4, 
      h["109"], 
      h["110"], 
      h["150"], 
      h["167"] 

    }'
```

Comment: You do not need to escape the `[` to use then in field separators, this is ok `-F"[][]"`

Comment: `-F[][, ]` worked for me. `-F[, ][]` produced the error message "_awk: fatal: Unmatched [ or [^: /[, ][]/_".